# How can I replace a string with another string using an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to work with an external array that should transform my file endings into another string:

This is my `fileTypes.php`:

```
return array(
'mp3'   => 'fa-music',
'jpeg'  => 'fa-picture-o',
);
```

And this is my `index.php`:

```
$fileTypes = require('fileTypes.php');
$file = "mymusic.mp3"
$fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

echo $fileTypes['fileExt'];
```

I do not really get it run. I must have some basic problem in understanding :(
I get an empty result. But the result I wish is `fa-music`.

Comment: Besides your missing semicolon, you want to use the variable `$fileExt` as index and not the string `fileExt` (Add error reporting: ``ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);``)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fileTypes.php` file would be like this:

```
$fileTypes = array(
  'mp3'   => 'fa-music',
  'jpeg'  => 'fa-picture-o',
);
```

Now, just include that file in your main script:

```
require('fileTypes.php');
$file = "mymusic.mp3";
$fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

echo $fileTypes[$fileExt];
```